# After adding a post, no data is output acf

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

After the program has been programmed to add a post through the function

```
wp_insert_post()
```

Can not get data and fields in acf plugin.
The data is available inside the post, in the fields, but not on the client side.
The output is obtained only after clicking the "Update" button inside the administrative part. After that, the data is output
Filling the post is as follows:

```
   $post_data = array(
        'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags($item->name),
        'post_content'  => "",
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_date'     => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'post_category' => array(3,13,2)
    );

    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );

    update_field( "link_to_1", $item->image, $post_id );
    update_field( "link_to_2", $item->tour, $post_id );
```

The conclusion on the client side is as follows:

```
<img src="<?php the_field('link_to_1');?>"/>
```

Comment: Your meta key name is wrong

Comment: sorry, i changed meta-key in this code. All meta keys is true. Not working

Comment: How you getting $item->image i mean where is the loop or something which is having $item variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that link_to_1 is storing image url .

In acf field you have given the return value as image url.

```
<img src="<?php the_field('link_to_1');?>"/>
```